# Spark turn off logging when using spark-submit

Tags: scala, apache-spark, log4j

I am running a scala Spark application to be submitted vi spark-submit:

```
spark-submit --class "com.foo.bar.MyClass" \
         --master yarn \
         --driver-memory 1g \
         --executor-memory 1g \
         --num-executors 2 \
         --executor-cores 2 \
         --jars <path-to>/MyJar.jar \
                <path-to>/MyJar.jar
```

I have tried just about every configuration of log4j I can think of or found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40608412/how-can-set-the-default-spark-logging-level), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31951728/how-to-set-up-logging-level-for-spark-application-in-intellij-idea), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25193488/how-to-turn-off-info-logging-in-pyspark) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28840438/how-to-override-sparks-log4j-properties-per-driver), among others.  I have put into my code the lines:

```
Logger.getRootLogger().setLevel(Level.WARN)
```

Among other lines, trying to suppress just individual classes.

I have also put a line of output in my Main to prove what level it is at:

```
println("Log level = " + LogManager.getRootLogger.getLevel())
```

It will show whatever I change the values to.  If I change the setlevel line of code above, it always prints out that value, if I take the line of code out, it will print whatever I have in the SPARK_HOME/conf/log4j.properties file, and if I addd the --conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions" lines, it will show what I put in there.

Bottom line, I can change any of those settings, and the application prints out what the log level is set at, but regardless, I get MBs of logging from Spark.

Any other suggestions on how to disable all the verbose logging from Spark?

Answer (score 1):

1. Create log4j-configurations.properties from
   log4j.properties/template
2. Add it under conf or configurations
   folder of your project
3. Add the lines below to the script using
   spark-submit:

---

---

```
--conf 'spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=prop/file/location'\
--conf 'spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=prop/file/location'\
```